# Ubuntu "Open with" dialog option empty?

Tags: firefox

Since my update to Ubuntu Jammy (22.04) the Firefox "Opening " dialog that appears, when downloading/opening a file only shows a blank entry for the "Open with" option:

[image: Firefox Open File Dialog (Open With)]

Which configuration option controls how this drop down is populated? Is this a Firefox issue or could it be that something got messed up with my MIME settings in the system. The `eog` (Eye of Gnome) image viewer is installed and I can correctly open and view the file if I save it first.

This used to work until the recent upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be a bug with the snap version of Firefox shipped with Ubuntu 22.04. The workaround is to replace the snap version of Firefox with the apt version, e.g. from the Mozilla Team [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Emozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).

One needs to pin the PPA version to higher priority.
See [How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/124466)  for more details.

Comment: That solved it immediately. I can imagine that this is going to be a pretty controversial change.